# Is it possible to use in the same class, different implementation of the same interface, using services in Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection

In this
example Temp2 overwrites Temp1->

```
services.AddSingleton<ITemp1, Temp1>();
services.AddSingleton<ITemp1, Temp2>();
```

Possibily like that ->

```
services.AddSingleton<Temp1>();
services.AddSingleton<Temp2>();
```

But i need to use interface also.
ITemp1 ->

```
interface ITemp1
{
void writeSomething();
}
```

Temp1 ->

```
Temp1 : ITemp1
{
void writeSomething(){ Console.WriteLine("First temp!")}
}
```

Temp2 ->

```
Temp2 : ITemp1
{
void writeSomething(){ Console.WriteLine("Second temp!")}
}
```

And then i wish to use such class, where i need Temp1 - use interface implementation ITemp1 - class Temp1, and Temp2 - use interface implementation ITemp1 - class Temp2. But alas, they will both use the implementation of the last registered service.

```
class SomeClass
{
   private readonly ITemp1 _Temp1;
   private readonly ITemp1 _Temp2;

   public SomeClass(ITemp1 Temp1, ITemp1 Temp2)
   {
      this._Temp1 = Temp1;
      this._Temp2 = Temp2;
   }

}
```

Comment: The Temp1 and Temp2 implementations are used in different places. So you need to make a bind to these different places. Please provide more information. Specify where and how these types are used.

Comment: As @AlexanderPetrov said without seeing how you want to use this interface in classes depending on it this question is very hard to answer. There is nothing wrong with the code shown so far - so the question really need some [edit] to be answerable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could tackle the problem this way:

```
services.AddSingleton<ITemp1, Temp1>();
services.AddSingleton<ITemp1, Temp2>();
```

and then whenever you want to get a particular instance do it this way:

```
var services = serviceProvider.GetServices<ITemp1>();
var temp2Serv = services.FirstOrDefault(x => x.GetType() == typeof(Temp2));
```

Comment: Or just `services.OfType<Temp2>().FirstOrDefault();` since we are already using LINQ.

Comment: Side note: registering multiple implementation to be used at the same time nor registering multiple implmentation to be automatically picked based on conditions/context are not "pretty unique" scenarios for using dependency injection. Deciding which implmentation of an interface to return from potentially several registered at the same time is *the core responsibility* of a container...

Comment: @Karl-JohanSjögren thanks first time i saw that wat to get it! 
AlexeiLevenkov You are right i ll remove my objective view on the matter

Answer (score 0):

One of the options you might use is "Named registration" which is not supported by default implementation of DI but that can be easily extended with external implementations, like Autofac. With Autofac, that might look like

```
var autofacContainerBuilder = new ContainerBuilder();
autofacContainerBuilder.RegisterType<Temp1>().As<ITemp>().Named<ITemp>("Temp1").SingleInstance();
autofacContainerBuilder.RegisterType<Temp2>().As<ITemp>().Named<ITemp>("Temp2").SingleInstance();
```

then once you registered everything, add that types to to your `IServiceCollection` instance, like

```
autofacContainerBuilder.Populate(services);
```

Then somewhere in your code, you might inject named instance, like:

```
     class MyClass
    {
        public MyClass([KeyFilter("temp1")]ITemp dep)
        {
            dep.SomeMethod();
        }
    }
```

or you might inject `ILifetimeScope` provided by autofac and call

```
scope.ResolveNamed<ITemp>("Temp1");
```

for details, refer to [autofac documentation](https://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html)

Autofac is not the only external DI provider, there are multiple other choices which might provide same feature